# Linear regression with dummy variables: p-value calculation

Tags: regression, categorical-data

-The standard procedure (general case) for finding p-values for linear regression coefficients is usually like this:

$$Y=b_{0}+b_{1}X+\epsilon$$

Since

$\hat{ b_{1} }=\frac{\sum Y_{i}(x_{i}-\overline{ x })}{S_{xx}}$

$\hat{ b_{0} }=\overline{ Y }-\hat{ b_{1} }\overline{ x }$

$S_{xx}=\sum(x-\overline{ x })^{2}$

Then if $Y \sim f_{\vec \theta}(x)$ then $\hat b_{i}\sim g_{\vec \theta;b_{i}}(x)$, hence for $H_{0}:b_{i}=0$ we can calculate $\Pr(|h(\hat b_{i} )|>c)=1-\gamma$.

-Example (normal case):

If $Y\sim N(b_0+b_1x,\sigma^{2})$ then $b_{1}\sim N(b_{1},\frac{\sigma^{2}}{S_{xx}})$, hence $\Pr(\left| \sqrt{\frac{(n-2)S_{xx}}{SS_{E}}}\hat{ b }_{1} \right|>c)=1-\gamma \Rightarrow c=t_{n-2}(\frac{1+\gamma}{2})$

Question:

If I have a linear regression with dummy variables can I get a simplified expression for the computation of p-values ($1-\gamma$)?

Motivation:

Suppose we want to **use distributions more complicated than normal or a different fitting method**, p-value computations may become complicated.

Comment: Why would you want one, if we may ask?

Comment: By writing *variables* (in the plural) you imply this is a multiple regression setting and by focusing on *dummy* [i.e., categorical] variables you suggest you are interested in [ANOVA](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anova?sort=votes&pageSize=30), which perhaps offers the simplification you seek.

Comment: There a lot of ANOVA models, which one are you referring to? Note that I'm also considering non-normal responses, it's for a code in R I'm writting.

Comment: user3083324 - rather, you should say which collections of dummies you were referring to in your question, and we can then figure out which ANOVA your question corresponds to. ANOVA is easy in R, either via `aov` or `lm`. However, it would be unusual to test individual dummies; normally you're interested in the collection (easily tested with `anova`). The commands give you p-values directly.

Comment: It's my understanding that **lm** only accepts normal response. Furthermore **glm** only let's me work with a predefined family of distributions. The reason for testing individual dummies is I am studying the [Multiple comparisons problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

Comment: Your comments seem inconsistent with your question. Your question is predicated on a normal response, but your comments say you want to do something when the response isn't normal. Please clarify what you want to do (in your question).

Comment: @Glen_b I solved this using bootstrap, but I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer.

Comment: You could write a description of what you did as an answer. It may be useful to others. If I'd understood the situation before you solved it (I didn't see your edit until you replied to my comment), I might have suggested GLMs or perhaps something based on robust approaches, or possibly using permutation tests for inference on the slope.